# Selenium Webdriver for gwt multi upload component

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, selenium, xpath

Case 1: I am trying to automate multiple file upload functionality. Whatever xpath I am giving is finding the element properly, but when I am executing program **(using `WebDriverWait` class)** it is failing, giving following error

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.className: gwt-FileUpload
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'`

Case 2: I am trying to automate upload files from local server. Whatever xpath I am giving is finding the element properly, but when I am executing program **(without using `WebDriverWait` class)** it is failing, giving following error:

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //input[@class='gwt-FileUpload is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@class='gwt-FileUpload`

Code is as follows:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://localhost:8080/application/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ type='text']" )).sendKeys("test");//user name
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ type='password']")).sendKeys("test");//pwd
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='button']")).click();//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[@id='gwt-uid-8']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='gwt-uid-8']")).click();//dropdown selection
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='gwt-uid-3']")).click();//dropdown selection

/*wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
               wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(ByClassName.className("gwt-FileUpload")));*/

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='button DecoratedFileUpload-button']")).click();//button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='gwt-FileUpload")).sendKeys("D:/xyz.doc");
```

Please anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

I am not able to upload the file using gwt-upload even at [this link](http://gwtupload.alcala.org/gupld/gwtuploadsample.MultipleUploadSample/MultipleUploadSample.html).

Comment: It is better avoided using class attribute to identify element. You can use an attribute like file upload if it is available. Let me know if this helps. Also post html for the upload section.

Comment: Thanks @Vinay. Please check my edit. I tried the same functionality at that link but I couldn't upload the file.